# MS Teams - getAuthToken API failing on iOS

Tags: microsoft-teams

`msTeams.authentication.getAuthToken` is returning failure Callback with Error message- `Auth Library Error`. It is working fine for Android and Desktop. The issue only occurs on iOS.

Following is the code snippet for the reference,

```js
getClientToken() {
    return new Observable<any>(subscriber => {
      this.teamsService.authentication.getAuthToken({
        resources: ['https://graph.microsoft.com/openid',
          'https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read.all',
          'https://graph.microsoft.com/group.read.all',
          'https://graph.microsoft.com/groupmember.read.all'],
        successCallback: clientToken => {
          subscriber.next({ clientToken, type: this.authType });
          subscriber.complete();
        },
        failureCallback: reason => {
          subscriber.error(reason);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3HJ2.png)

Comment: Could you please share the device details and Teams client version?

Comment: Also share Teams JS SDK version used.

Comment: We have tried with 1.11.0 and 1.7.0 of Teams JS SDK
While iOS app details are like
Version - 3.17.0
Build - 3.17.77.2021173001/1013(general)
Calling version - 2021.34.01.8
Release Branch - 2021Sept-T2

Comment: Internal bug is raised for this issue. I will update you once it is fixed.

Comment: We have check and confirm that this issue is fixed and we are no longer seeing "_Auth library Error_" and we are able to get the access token. Could you please try and check if you are still able to reproduce this issue in the latest build?